# Cardinality problem: if $|A-B|=|B-A|$ then $|A| = |B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was trying to prove the following question:
1. we need to prove that if $|A-B|=|B-A|$ then $|A| = |B|$.

this is my answer so far:
Case 1: 
$$A \cap B = \varnothing$$

In this case:

$|A-B|= |A| =|B-A| = |B|$

then $|A|=|B|$.

Case 2:
$$A \cap B \ne \varnothing$$

In this case:

$$|A-B|=|A-(A \cap B)| = |B-A| = |B-(A \cap B)|$$

Am I on the right track? im not sure thats how I was supposed to prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set $A$ is the union of the two disjoint sets $A\cap B$ and $A-B$, so $|A|=|A\cap B|+|A-B|$. Now, if only we could show that $|B|=|A\cap B|+|B-A|$ . . .

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Will it be enought to write as proof the following:
Since we know that we have a bijection between A-B -> B-A
then we can use the following function between A->B Function:
(A n B) + (A - B) -> (B n A) + (B - A)

and because (A n B) = (B n A)
we can tell that its a bijection.
so |A| = |B|

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to get bogged down with the details here. But the simplest way would be to find a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

We are given that $|A-B|=|B-A|$, therefore there is a function $f\colon (A-B)\to (B-A)$ which is a bijection. Can you think of a way to extend $f$ to be a bijection between $A$ and $B$?